# How would I go about printing on plastic sheets?

Tags: print-design, resource-recommendations, print-production, hardware-recommendation

I have a laser printer, and I wish to print onto plastic sheets for creating boxes to hold playing cards. How would one go about the printing process, or is it even possible? What plastic should I use?

Answer (score 1):

Generally what you would put through a laser printer would be called Transparency Film.
Something like this:
[http://www.staples.com/office/supplies/StaplesProductDisplay?storeId=10001&catalogIdentifier=2&partNumber=829903&langid=-1&cid=PS:GooglePLAs:829903&ci_src=17588969&ci_sku=829903&KPID=829903](http://www.staples.com/office/supplies/StaplesProductDisplay?storeId=10001&catalogIdentifier=2&partNumber=829903&langid=-1&cid=PS%3aGooglePLAs:829903&ci_src=17588969&ci_sku=829903&KPID=829903)

But this is thin stuff. I'm not sure it would be sturdy enough for your application.

You could give it a go though if a laser printer is all you have. Maybe print on the transparency film, but frame your boxes with sturdier plastics.

Comment: Well, that sure would work for a while, but I'll need something a little better. How would silk screening fair?

Comment: more difficult than laser printing. Usually you would silkscreen on a material that could absorb the ink, paper or fabric etc. Plastic would work too, but you might need different inks or additional equipment. Getting the ink to set and dry properly is essential. Use Google, there are some how to's and videos out there.

Comment: Based on the question asking about laser printing, this is the correct answer. There are transparency sheets designed specifically for running through laser printers.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you need to consider not just a plastic but a laser printer, because during printing process heating is used and you have a chance to destroy your device.

You can check for specialized equipment at [Plastic Printers](http://www.plasticprinters.com/equipment/). 
I am sure they also have clean plastic cards ready for print.

Comment: Unfortunately, they only print on cards. I'm looking for Sheets.

Answer (score 0):

what his link pointed to (worked for me), and what you might be looking for is "Synthetic Paper"/"Polyester paper"

theres a couple of brands that make those, they are basically polyester.

Nekoosa Coated Synaps OM
Xerox Polyester
TerraSlate
Teslin
etc.